# How to convert a complex JSON array response to simple Json using C#

Tags: c#, json

I recieve response in this JSON format

```
{
"soap:Envelope":
{
    "@xmlns:soap":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","soap:Body":
    {
        "ns2:processPayment":
        {
            "@xmlns:ns2":"http://ws.cwt.ru/","Status":"SUCCESS","StatusCode":"000","StatusMessage":"SUCCESS","Payments":
            {
                "Payment":
                {
                    "InPaymentParameters":
                    {
                        "entry":
                        [
                            {"key":"FEE_AMOUNT","value":"100"},                             
                            {"key":"SOURCE_AMOUNT","value":"80000"},{"key":"SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER","value":"888117823"},
                            {"key":"DESTINATION_BANK_CB_ID","value":"BANK OF AMERICA"},
                            {"key":"DESCRIPTION","value":"chama"},
                            {"key":"merchantId","value":"1321"},{"key":"MERCHANT_ACQUIRER_CONTRACT_ID","value":"1"},
                            {"key":"DESTINATION_ACCOUNT","value":"01116132194100"},
                            {"key":"MERCHANT_ID","value":"admin"},
                            {"key":"REMOTE_TRANSACTION_ID","value":"000000086814933"},
                            {"key":"DESTINATION_CONNECTION_ID","value":"243"},
                            {"key":"FINANCE_OPERATION_TYPE","value":"WITHDRAWAL"},
                            {"key":"ISO8583_CARD_ACCEPTOR_ID","value":"000000000105817"},
                            {"key":"SOURCE_CONNECTION_ID","value":"243"},
                            {"key":"MESSAGE_ID","value":"139096"},
                            {"key":"ISO8583_CARD_ACCEPTOR_TERMINAL_ID","value":"POS00002"},
                            {"key":"OPERATION_ID","value":"756033604"},
                            {"key":"OPERATION_STATUS_MESSAGE"},
                            {"key":"OPERATION_STATUS","value":"SUCCESS"},
                            {"key":"SERVICE_NAME"},
                            {"key":"AUTHORIZATION_PASS","value":"admin"},
                            {"key":"AUTHORIZATION_LOGIN","value":"admin"},
                            {"key":"ISO8583_APPROVAL_CODE","value":"122127"},
                            {"key":"SOURCE_CARD_PAN"},
                            {"key":"SERVICE_TYPE","value":"FINANCE"},
                            {"key":"TRANSACTION_ID","value":"184139327"}
                        ]
                    },"OutPaymentParameters":null,"ServiceFields":null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

And would wish to put it in simple format like

```
{ "Status":"SUCCESS","StatusCode":"000","FEE_AMOUNT":"100", "SOURCE_AMOUNT":80000, "DESTINATION_BANK_CB_ID":"BANK OF AMERICA" }
```

using C#. How can this be achieved please? 
All responses follow the same format.
Any insight will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you receiving that format in the first place? It's XML (or more specifically, a SOAP response) converted to JSON. Skip the JSON step and simply parse the XML to an object. Also, what have you tried? There are tons of tutorials on parsing (deserializing) and generating (serializing) JSON.

Comment: It is an easy task and verbose however. You can deserialize the above data to an object instance then reserialize to get the new format. All the thing you can get by using json.net library

Comment: @CodeCaster it is json data, not xml

Comment: @Dan yes, it is an XML document formatted as JSON.

Comment: @CodeCaster i receive it in XML

Answer (score 0):

not in C# but I can provide a solution or at least a way of converting this JSON response to first tabular format in SQL Server then again convert to desired JSON format as in following SQL code

```
;with cte as
(

select
--  j2.[@xmlns:soap],
--  j4.[@xmlns:ns2],
    j4.[Status],
    j4.[StatusCode],
--  j4.[StatusMessage],
    j8.[key],
    j8.[value]
from openjson(@json) with (
    [soap:Envelope] nvarchar(max) as json
) as j1
cross apply openjson(j1.[soap:Envelope]) with (
    [@xmlns:soap] nvarchar(max) ,
    [soap:Body] nvarchar(max) as json
) as j2
cross apply openjson(j2.[soap:Body]) with (
    [ns2:processPayment] nvarchar(max) as json
) as j3
cross apply openjson(j3.[ns2:processPayment]) with (
    [@xmlns:ns2] nvarchar(max),
    [Status] nvarchar(max),
    [StatusCode] nvarchar(max),
    [StatusMessage] nvarchar(max),
    Payments nvarchar(max) as json
) as j4
cross apply openjson(j4.[Payments]) with (
    [Payment] nvarchar(max) as json
) as j5
cross apply openjson(j5.[Payment]) with (
    InPaymentParameters nvarchar(max) as json,
    OutPaymentParameters nvarchar(max) as json,
    ServiceFields nvarchar(max) as json
) as j6
cross apply openjson(j6.InPaymentParameters) with (
    [entry] nvarchar(max) as json
) as j7
cross apply openjson(j7.[entry]) with (
    [key] nvarchar(max),
    [value] nvarchar(max)
) as j8
where 
    [key] in ('FEE_AMOUNT','SOURCE_AMOUNT','DESTINATION_BANK_CB_ID')
)
select 
    [Status], 
    [StatusCode], 
    max(FEE_AMOUNT) as FEE_AMOUNT,
    max(SOURCE_AMOUNT) as SOURCE_AMOUNT,
    max(DESTINATION_BANK_CB_ID) as DESTINATION_BANK_CB_ID
from (
select
    [Status],
    [StatusCode],
    case when [key] = 'FEE_AMOUNT' then [value] end as FEE_AMOUNT,
    case when [key] = 'SOURCE_AMOUNT' then [value] end as SOURCE_AMOUNT,
    case when [key] = 'DESTINATION_BANK_CB_ID' then [value] end as DESTINATION_BANK_CB_ID
from cte
) t
group by [Status], [StatusCode]
for json auto
```

[image]

This way of [cascading OpenJSON calls in CROSS APPLY joins](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/parse-json-response-of-aws-amazon-transcribe-service-on-sql-server-using-openjson.aspx) can help to convert complex JSON structures to table format